# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]

Tags: javascript, callback, delay

I want to Implement a function which can run a given function after a delay.

Arguments:

- callback: the function to execute after the delay
- delay: number of milliseconds to wait
- data: the one (and only) argument to pass to the callback

And this was my code

```
let cb = function(x) {
  console.log(x);
};

const doShortly = function(callback, delay, data) {
  let result = setTimeout(callback(data), delay);
  return result;
};

console.log(doShortly(cb, 500, 'hi'));
```

I get TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK] when I run the code. May I know how to fix this. TIA.

Comment: <script>
let cb = function(x) {
  console.log(x);
};
const doShortly = function(callback, delay, data) {
  let result = setTimeout(null, delay);
callback(data);
  return result;
};

console.log(doShortly(cb, 500, 'hi'));
</script> Your result variable is wrong. The setTimeout function takes a callback too. But you are running the callback within setTimeout.

Comment: This is a duplicate, please look at this post/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/944670

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` for that directly. All the
params after the delay param, will be passed to the callback function in the same order :)

```js
let cb = function(x) {
  console.log(x);
};

const doShortly = function(callback, delay, data) {
  let result = setTimeout(callback, delay, data);
  return result;
};

console.log(doShortly(cb, 500, 'hi')); // or: setTimeout(cb, 500, 'hi')
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you :)